# Column next to BootStrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to put a `<div class="col-md-6">Test</div>` to the right of my BootStrap Carousel (`<header class="carousel">...</header>`).

How can I achieve this? I've tried inline styles for `<header>` such as margin:none, width:200px, but `<header>` still has a right margin. I've also tried to wrap `<header class="carousel">` with `<div class="col-md-6">`, but my bootstrap carousel disappears for some bizarre reason.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukaqej69/2/. Sorry about the extraneous CSS and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the `carousel` class from the `<header>` and use Bootstraps column grid to set the `<div>`s side by side, like this:

```
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="carousel col-md-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's a fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/g6bgxvad/

Comment: When I put my carousel in `row`, it disappears. Also, it seems the fiddle you provided does not exhibit the behavior where the column is next to the carousel. +1 for your input.

Comment: @chakeda, increase the Results pane, since the example uses `col-md-6`, it wraps.

Comment: Ah, I see it. I will implement this now

Comment: Thanks mate, you led me in the right direction. Completed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukaqej69/3/